# Change Color from material outlined button doesn't work

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme, android-styles, material-components-android

I want to change the color of the active toggle button. But just the change of the rippleColor makes a difference.
I wish to customize the background color of the active button and the text color.

```
<style name="ToggleButtonGroupStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
            <item name="rippleColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

In the following toggleButtonGroup I used this style from above:

```
         <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@+id/priority_btn_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            app:selectionRequired="true"
            app:singleSelection="true"
            app:checkedButton="@+id/btn_one"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_one"
                style="@style/ToggleButtonGroupStyle"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/priority_btn_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:shadowColor="@color/project_text"
                android:text="0" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/ToggleButtonGroupStyle"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/priority_btn_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="!" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/ToggleButtonGroupStyle"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/priority_btn_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="!!" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/ToggleButtonGroupStyle"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="!!!" />


        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

Could anybody give me a hint what the problem here is?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The background color of the checked buttons is based on the **`colorPrimary`** attribute.
You can use:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_one"
    style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Custom.Button"
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.Custom.Button" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

[image]

or you can use a custom style with:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_one"
        style="@style/ToggleButtonGroupStyle"
```

with:

```
<style name="ToggleButtonGroupStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/custom_selector</item>
</style>


<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/..." android:state_checked="true"/>  <!-- selected color -->
    <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: How can I make the button multi-line?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77982778/materialbuttons-in-materialbuttontogglegroup-cant-do-wrap-content