# MaterialButton style being overridden, how do I keep it?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-styles, material-components-android

I'm trying to use a `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` inside my `BottomSheetDialog`. However the style for the button is being overriden by the current theme I'm using for the `BottomSheet`

**In a regular fragment:**

Using the attribute

`style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"`

I have this blue outline on my `Material Button` inside my `ToggleGroup`

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggle_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:checkedButton="@+id/btnOne"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:selectionRequired="true"
        app:singleSelection="true">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>


    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

[image]

**But when using it inside my `BottomSheet` I get this:**

[image]

The theme for bottom sheet I'm using:

```
<style name="Theme.TestApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        ...
        
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

```
    <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetRoundedCorners</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomSheetRoundedCorners" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bgr_bottomsheet_round_corners</item>
    </style>
```

How can I keep the style

`style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"`

for the `MaterialButton` while using the `BottomSheet`'s theme?

**Edit:______________________________**

I've tried adding

`<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton</item>` to my `BottomSheet`'s theme but it doesn't do anything.

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetRoundedCorners</item>
        <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton</item>
    </style>
```

Have also tried it with

`<item name="materialButtonStyle">?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle</item>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this theme:

```
<style name="BottomSheet" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.BottomSheetDialog"/>

<style name="Theme.TestApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/BottomSheet</item>
```

**DO NOT USE THEME.DESIGN.LIGHT**

Comment: If I use ```DayNight``` it doesn't use my primary color but uses the secondary color

Comment: I test it, it works, it uses primary color if you declare this style in your both day and night theme. maybe you give a custom color/style to your button

Comment: It's giving me the color purple. I don't have the color purple anywhere inside my app...
https://i.imgur.com/qdc8pLm.png I have tried uninstall reinstalling the app I checked both themes, day and night, they both don't have purple

Comment: can you post your full code for the button and styles?

Comment: The default color is apparently purple from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65283532/11110509 but I can't change it. Can't change it to blue with ```android:textColorHighlight="@color/blueColor"``` Doesn't do anything

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64239236/11110509 This answer allowed me to remove the default purple color to my blue color. Thanks for your help.